# Run a for loop in a python class innit function to save multiple different self.example variables in my class

Tags: python, class, for-loop, python-3.7, self

I wan to create a class, in this case example where you can run a for loop in the `__init__` function that will save multiple variables in the class as `self`. As of now my code is as follows:

```py
inputs = [[1,2,3,4,2], [8,5,3,2,3], [7,4,3,2,4], [9,9,3,4,5]]

class Example:
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        for i in range(0, len(inputs)):
            for j in range (0, len(inputs[i])):
                self.inputs = inputs[i][j]


variables = Example(inputs)
print(variables.inputs)
```

This returns `5` of course because it will save the last iteration of the for loop, which is `5`. But say I wanted to save input `1` as `self.input_1` and input `2` as `self.input_2` ... and the last input as `self.input_4_5`. I don't know if I will have to do a different alternative but can anyone do this?

Comment: Don't put numbers on the end of variable names. Use a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't append numbers to variable names. This is a path to madness. Just use lists instead:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self.inputs = inputs
```

Comment: I am aware that about lists. What I want to do is create a for loop that iterates through the list and saves each value to a new variable that I can refer to within that class using self.

Comment: @Rob Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Rob I ask because this sounds like an XY problem. What I mean is that you are trying to do something and you found a solution that doesn't quite work. Now you are asking how to finish that solution. However, I suspect that there is a better solution to the original thing you are trying to do. With some more information, we can point you in a different direction that will solve your original problem more easily.

Comment: I have started to write a pygame, and each level contains these inputs of arrays. 3x3 - 6x6 arrays are used. I initially have a for loop like above except I: `self.text = str(input[i][j])` then `font.render(self.text)` in various places on the screen. The problem is I need to save each of these texts as there own variable inside the class so that I can manipulate it further. Its very difficult to explain, but long story short, if I can do the for loop explained above I can start to manipulate my pygame the way I need to.

Comment: @Rob "Save each text as its own variable" doesn't sound like the right path to go down. Perhaps you could create a class that represents a single cell in the grid. Then you can store a 2D array of instances of this class.